# I cannot press enter on the button

Tags: c, winapi

This is my first program in C using WINAPI.
When I click the button with my mouse, everything is OK, but I cannot press the button with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On the other hand, <kbd>Space</kbd> is working.

I'm guessing that the problem is in "IsDialogMessage" but I cannot solve it.

This is my code in WinMain:

```
/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg) && msg.wParam != VK_RETURN  )
    {
        /* Already handled by dialog manager */
    }
    else {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    }
}
```

and this is my LRESULT CALLBACK code :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK wg_WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
static HWND cb_handle = 0;
static HWND g_hButtonLogin = 0;
static HWND g_hButtonConfig = 0;

static HWND hEditLogin = 0;
static HWND hLabelLogin = 0;

static HWND hEditPass = 0;
static HWND hLabelPass = 0;

static int pozycja_3 = 0;

struct sesslist slist;

switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
    // LOGIN 
    hLabelLogin = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 20, 20, 40, 20, hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    hEditLogin = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, 80, 20, 150, 25,
        hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

    // PASSWORD 
    hLabelPass = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 20, 50, 40, 20, hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
    hEditPass = CreateWindowEx(0, "EDIT", NULL, ES_PASSWORD | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, 80, 50, 150, 25,
        hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

    SetWindowText(hLabelLogin, "Login:");
    SetWindowText(hLabelPass, "Hasło:");

    // COMBOBOX 
    cb_handle = CreateWindowEx(0, "COMBOBOX", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_TABSTOP, 80, 80, 150, 25 * 4, hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);

    get_sesslist(&slist, TRUE);

    // MessageBox(hwnd, slist.sessions[1] , "yyyyy", 0);
    int a = 1;
    while (slist.sessions[a] != NULL)
    {
        SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, slist.sessions[a]);
        a++;
    }
    SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_SETCURSEL, 3, (LPARAM)"4");

    /*SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"MFG1");
    SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"MFG2");
    pozycja_3 = SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"3");
    SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"4");
    SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, (LPARAM)"4");*/

    g_hButtonConfig = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "BUTTON", "*", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        260, 20, 20, 20, hwnd, NULL, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL);
```

**Then I Create Button "Zaloguj"**

```
g_hButtonLogin = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "BUTTON", "Zaloguj", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        20, 120, 250, 30, hwnd, NULL , ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance ) ;

    CenterWindow(hwnd);

    SetFocus(hEditLogin);
    // wg_hDlgCurrent = hEditLogin;


}
break;
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if ((HWND)lParam == g_hButtonConfig)
    {
        do_config();
    }

    if ((HWND)lParam == g_hButtonLogin || (HWND)wParam == g_hButtonLogin)
    {
        if (1 == 1)
        {

            int idx_row;
            char *strText[256];

            idx_row = SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(cb_handle, CB_GETLBTEXT, idx_row, (LPARAM)strText);

            wg_selected_sess = strText;

            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
    }
    break;
}
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
    break;
}
default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
```

}

When I hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the "zaloguj" button, nothing happens.

Comment: The dialog manager can only help you if you have a dialog. You don't appear to have a dialog.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : 
I read that I need that :
            if (IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg) && msg.wParam != VK_RETURN)
to handle TAB key and WS_TABSTOP on my controls.

Comment: But you don't have a dialog, so `IsDialogMessage` won't help, and `msg.wParam != VK_RETURN` is just weird. Don't blindly copy code without trying to understand.

Comment: What's `&& msg.wParam != VK_RETURN` for? That's unusual, although I'm not sure if that can break anything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : without IsDialogMessage my TAB key doesn't allowing to change focus of my edit boxes.

Comment: @immibis : I add it with hope this could help me. To not filter RETURN key with IsDialogMessage.

Comment: You don't have a dialog. Do you know what a dialog is? It seems to me that you are tackling this the wrong way. You just want to find a magic incantation and don't want to learn. My interest in being here is in helping people learn. I'm not remotely motivated to supply magic incantations if no learning occurs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I did not. I will try find something with google. This dialog is good track to solve this ?

Comment: The dialog manager can do this for you. Then again, you might not want to make this window be a dialog. In which case you need to take over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I am sorry for dumb questions. I just start my journey with WINAPI and I have no idea yet what else I do not know. Can You recommend any book with strong basics?

Comment: Petzold's Programming Windows

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: [IsDialogMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx) can be used with any window, that contains controls. However, you do have to handle [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx) and [DM_GETDEFID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645406.aspx) to allow the system to implement standard behavior for the default button (the button that's invoked when pressing the [Enter] key).

Comment: @IInspectable Those are the things that make it into a dialog I guess. Or at least to look like a dialog.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not at all. This just adds keyboard navigation. What makes a window a dialog is its class (`#32770`) together with dialog-specific extra window memory ([DWLP_*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx)), and the particularities of the [DialogProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable The question is about keyboard navigation

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, I try to use RETURN key on the "Zaloguj" button and I don't want to lose "Focus" handling - which i get with isDialogMessage() .